# jquery ui slider page up/down increment value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Is there a way to set by how much the slider moves when someone presses page up or page down? Currently, my slider moves by a value which is equivalent to one fifth of the slider range. I would like to set it to move by, say, 10 steps. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 'step' option for that:

```
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50
    });
```

To solve the page up/ page down strange behavior, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SPDBw/

Comment: Thanks, but the 'step' option affects by how much the slider moves with the arrow keys. I'd like to keep that at '1'. Instead, I want to change the amount it moves when the **page up/down** buttons are pressed.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know it has a different behavior when using page up/page down and I believe it's a bug as it makes a nonsense result.
I believe you'll have to directly prevent their default behavior and make a function that makes them work right.

Comment: Just updated my answer with this custom pageup/pagedown behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Robyflc. How can update the sample you gave me if there are multiple sliders and each slider has two scrollers (values)? I would like the the keystroke to only affect the selected scroller.

Comment: By "each slider has two scrollers" you mean something link this range example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range?

Answer (score 0):

From version **1.8.** to **1.11.**, they've put the variable `numPages` inside the ui.slider container, and fixed it to **5**.

Even if you override the keyCode handler to recognize the keys "PageUp" and 'PageDown" wouldn't fix the problem.

***BUT***, as a workaround, you can override this variable, contained in the prototype scope of the slider widget, at the beggining of your page load.

**Pros**: I don't need to worry about fetching the objects' *max* and *min* values

**Cons**: Solution is only a workaround, and solution can(and *will*) be broken in a future patch.

What I did was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ui.slider.prototype.numPages = 10;
});
```

Hope it works ;)